# Java, local TCP server accepting HTTP requests from a browser

Tags: java, sockets

I am trying to "Write a Java program that is a TCP server that returns a HTTP response to a browser that displays the client’s IP address and the number of times it has connected to the server"

Currently what I think is happening. I am creating a server and listening to the port (input as a argument) for a request, then filling a byte array and converting that array to a string. I wish then to just see the request at this point.

My problem is if I do try to connect to this server by going to my web-browser and typing "localhost:1235" my browser just keeps saying "connecting to ..." and my program does nothing it just sits and waits.

How might I go about fixing/and implemented the rest of this? What could my current problem be?

So far here is my code

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;


public class TCPHTTP 
{
private static final int MAXFILELEN = 4096000;
static byte[] request = new byte[MAXFILELEN];
static String[] log;

public static void main (String args[])
{
    if (args.length != 1) 
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "Parameter(s): <Port>");

    int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]); 

    ServerSocket socket = null;
    Socket sock = null;

    try 
    {
        socket = new ServerSocket(port);
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        return;
    }
    for (;;) 
    {
        try 
        {
            sock = socket.accept();
            InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
            int offset = 0;
            int len = 0;
            while ((len = is.read(request, offset, MAXFILELEN - offset)) >= 0)
            {
                offset += len;
            }

            String s = new String(request);
            System.out.println(s);

            // Add the users IP to the log
            String from = "From: ";
            int loglen = log.length;
            int indexOfSenderIP = s.indexOf(from, 0);
            indexOfSenderIP += from.length();
            int indexOfNewline = s.indexOf("\n", indexOfSenderIP);
            String sendersIP = s.substring(indexOfSenderIP, indexOfNewline);
            log[loglen] = sendersIP;

            //Find out how many times the sender IP appears in the log
            int timesVisited = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < log.length; i++)
                if(log[i].endsWith(sendersIP))
                    timesVisited++;

            // Construct the HTTP response message
            String httpResponse = "";

            OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
            os.write(httpResponse.getBytes());

            os.close();
            is.close();
            sock.close();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            break; 
        }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a `Content-Length` header to specify the size of your response so the browser knows how much to read.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why your program freezes is that it waits for the client to close connection (read returns a value that's <0 after an eof).
you should read until you receive a double [cr][lf] from the client, that's what marks the ending of the http header

Comment: So something like this "boolean leave = false;
    while ((len = is.read(request, offset, MAXFILELEN - offset)) >= 0 && leave == false)
    {
     offset += len;
     String stmp = new String(request);
     if(stmp.contains("\r\n\r\n"));
      leave = true;
    }"

Comment: it should do (a single \r\n should work too), also, you can use break instead of that boolean leave

Answer (score 0):

```
String httpResponse = "";
```

That's not a valid HTTP response. Your browser is waiting for a proper response. Send one.

Answer (score -1):

from what i see, you closed the socket before answering the client's request

also, i tested your code, and that while cycle never ends

Comment: I changed the code above. Look at it now. I still have the same problem of the browser saying "connecting ...."

Comment: that while cycle never ends, and also it has no reason to exist since you're not gonna use that data. you can remove it and answer the client immediately, or fix it

Comment: But don't I need to read the request so that I can find the senders IP? What I think that while is doing is reading the entire request until it reaches the end. So what is it actually doing?

Comment: no, you can get the sender's ip from the socket (.getInetAddress() method)